# is there some profiling and coverage library for rust?

Tags: networking, distributed, profiling, protocol, rust

This question is related to a common criticism of the model for sharing computing resources on blockchains (often seen on economics), based on accounting of participation of various users on the network, on the various proof of ..., so far so good, the problem is the productivity, or content, of that participation, which apart from the actual necessary network stability, security and availability, just serves to produce endless numbers for trade, whose sense of necessity still depends on the ideology of the participants.

Surely the protocols are great for accounting, the issue considered is just the target of that accounting. So what I am intending to do is to target the accounting to just the execution of the code ported to the network, and related to the necessities of the network itself, to the extent that things are still needed.

**So what I am asking in order to implement it, are rust libraries that provide functions for code coverage and profiling.**

Also in order to control overhead, such functions may be executed at intervals, to equilibrate among accountability and performance